# Incrementing game streak on next day using local storage

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

I am creating a game in which the user can play once every day (I am switching days in UTC, not local time). Everything works, except that I'm having trouble incrementing the streak count, or how many days they've played in a row. I can break the streak just fine - reset it to 0 if >1 day elapses between plays - but I can't get it to increment when playing on consecutive days. It just gets stuck at 1. Please note: I am not a coder, I am an elementary school teacher doing this for fun, so apologies if I make noob mistakes.

Here is what I have. I have tried too many variations to list them all here. I've only been doing JavaScript for a few months, so I feel like I'm missing something basic. First, I listen for the user to submit a guess and also check if their last guess is today. If the last guess is today, I store it in localStorage. If not, do nothing. (Note: the function datesAreSameDay checks if the dates are the same; it is used elsewhere in the code and works fine.)

```
const formForStreak = document.querySelector('form');
const todayStreak = new Date().toISOString();

formForStreak.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    const streakTime = new Date().toISOString;
    const todayForStreak = new Date(todayStreak);
    if (datesAreSameDay(streakTime, todayForStreak)){
        localStorage.setItem("streakLastGuessDate", streakTime.toISOString())
    } else if (!datesAreSameDay(streakTime,todayForStreak)){
        console.log("Do something here")
    }
})
```

Then, I constitute some variables for the streak last guess date, and also create a function to break the streak if there's a gap of more than one day. When the page loads, I call the function, update localStorage, and also the place in the HTML where the streak count is displayed.

```
// Create a new variable for the date of the last guess - grab from local storage
const streakLastGuess = localStorage.getItem("streakLastGuessDate");
// Get the streak count from localStorage or set it to one if not found
let streakCount = localStorage.getItem("streakCount") || 0;

//function to break streak if gap of  > 1 day
function breakStreak (date1, date2) {
  return date1.getUTCFullYear() > date2.getUTCFullYear() + 1 ||
      date1.getUTCMonth() > date2.getUTCMonth() + 1 ||
      date1.getUTCDate() > date2.getUTCDate() + 1;

// onload, do this:
window.onload = function() {

if (streakLastGuess){
    const breakLastGuessTimeStreak = new Date(streakLastGuess);
    const todayToday = new Date();
    if (breakStreak(todayToday, breakLastGuessTimeStreak)){
        streakCount = 0;
    localStorage.setItem("myStreak", JSON.stringify(streakCount));
    console.log("You broke your streak! Counter set to 0.")
    document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(streakCount);
    } else {
        streakCount++;
        document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(streakCount);
        localStorage.setItem("myStreak", JSON.stringify(streakCount));
        console.log("Hurray, let's add one to your streak!");
    }
    document.getElementById("streak").firstChild.nodeValue = streakCount;

    localStorage.setItem("myStreak", JSON.stringify(streakCount));
}};
```

The console.log seems to indicate that my function works, but the streak isn't being incremented in localStorage or on the page. So, I think the issue is in the else statement of the function being called when the window loads. I've tried moving this out of window.onload, but then nothing seems to work. Would greatly appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: A general remark: You must be aware that any if you maintain the streak on the client (in the local storage), a malicious user can manipulate it. Everything you want to _enforce_ must be implemented on the _server_ (which is controlled by you), not on the _client_ (which is controlled by the user).

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am aware of this; I am making a very chill little game that is my first-ever project. If someone wants to cheat on a game about guessing works of classic literature, then I suppose I just feel sorry for them. One day perhaps I will be more advanced than I am now and make something more complicated. For now, I'm just trying to master the basics and make something chill for a friend of mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following function works with `Date` objects that represent a given date by midnight in UTC, and it compares the current end of the streak with yesterday or today to maintain the streak length.

The function can be called as `<body onload="maintainStreak()">`, for example.

```js
function maintainStreak() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setUTCHours(0);
  today.setUTCMinutes(0);
  today.setUTCSeconds(0);
  today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  var streakLength;
  var streakEnd = localStorage.getItem("streakEnd");
  if (streakEnd) {
    streakEnd = new Date(streakEnd);
    streakLength = Number(localStorage.getItem("streakLength"));
    var yesterday = new Date(today);
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    if (streakEnd.getTime() === yesterday.getTime()) {
      streakEnd = today;
      streakLength++;
    } else if (streakEnd.getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
      /* Game was already played today */
      return false;
    } else
      streakEnd = undefined;
  }
  if (!streakEnd) {
    streakEnd = today;
    streakLength = 1;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("streakEnd", streakEnd.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
  localStorage.setItem("streakLength", streakLength);
  return true;
}
```

The function return `true` unless the game was already played today. In the latter case, you may display different content.